# GoogleVis does not show chart in RStudio

Tags: r, rstudio, googlevis

I am trying to use googleVis-0.5.10 with RStudio 0.99.473 on Windows 7. I can generate charts just fine, but they always opened in a new browser window. The code is simple, no extra options are set:

```
lineChart <- gvisLineChart(data,
                       options = list(
                         selectionMode = "multiple",
                         focusTarget = "category",
                         tooltip = "{ trigger : 'focus', aggregationTarget: 'auto' }")
                       )
plot(lineChart)
```

I have tried to call viewer manually by providing url from the opened browser window:

```
rstudio::viewer("http://127.0.0.1:10529/custom/googleVis/LineChartIDc6837e37021.html")
```

But it shows almost an empty screen:

[image]

I think it is some kind of a security issue as when I right click RStudio Viewer window and open web inspector, I see there is a javascript error:

```
Failed to load resource: Unable to init SSL Context:  https://www.google.com/jsapi?callback=displayChartLineChartIDc6837e37021
```

If I am right, is there a way to instruct RStudio to trust content from www.google.com domain? Or, if I am wrong, how can I fix the problem?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1):

I think your flash player is not enabled. In chrome type:

```
chrome://plugins
```

and check the flash player checkbox and try again.

Comment: "This site can’t be reached" Version 74.0.3729.169 (Official Build) (64-bit)

Answer (score 1):

Inda's answer is correct, except now the path to change your Chrome flash settings is

[chrome://settings/content](http://chrome://settings/content)